# What happened to tutorials

Tags: spring

Last day in http://spring.io/guides was 3 tutorials what happened to them? Is it possible to read or watch them or any archive or sth?

Comment: Looking at the site there are plenty of guides...

Answer (score 0):

Using archive.org:

http://web.archive.org/web/20140715102625/https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/data/

http://web.archive.org/web/20140626113844/http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/web/

No guarantees as to accuracy or depth of these guides.

Comment: Thank You. I want vote up for u but not enaugh rep, anyway good idea :D. Maybe do you know any other good full tutorials to learn spring?